# React - prop array of values

Tags: reactjs

This is my **SearchForm.js**  class, `experience` prop must be array of values with `id` and `name`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
       position: '',
       area: '',
       date: '',
       experience: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
          }  
      }        
     }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://example.com/dictionaries/', 
            headers: { 
                'User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)', 
                'HH-User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)',  
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
            })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.experience);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }


    render() {
        return ( 
            <form className='form search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-row">         
                    <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label htmlFor="experience">Experience</label>
                        <select className="form-control" name="experience" id="experience" onChange={this.handleExperienceChange} value={this.state.experience}>
                {/* <option key={this.props.experience.id} value={this.props.experience.name}>
                            {this.props.experience.name}
                        </option> */}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchForm }
```

as result I get

[image]

How to put this values from `response.data.experience` in `experience` prop?

Comment: Use arrow functions, it'll lexically scope `this`. Change `then((function(response) {...}` to `then((response) => {...}`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the state like

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com/dictionaries/', 
    headers: { 
        'User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)', 
        'HH-User-Agent': 'React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)',  
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.experience);
    this.setState({experience: response.data.experience})
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And you can loop through the `experience` array by using this :

`{
    this.state.experience.map((value, index) =>
        <option key={value.id} value={value.name}> {value.name} </option>
    )
}`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at SearchForm.js:37` in this case

Comment: answer updated. You also need to bind the function to the class for use `this` inside

Comment: `.then((response) => {
            this.setState({experience: response.data.experience});
            console.log(this.experience);
            })` doesn't work either - `Undefined` in console

Comment: When I try `console.log(this.experience);` I get `Undefined`

Comment: for get values form state, use `this.state.experience`

Comment: ok, it helped. but  `<option key={this.state.experience.id} value={this.state.experience.name}>
                        {this.state.experience.name} 
                    </option>` doesn't work, `options` are empty

Comment: `this.state.experience` is an array so you need to loop through this to set options.

Comment: how to use loop here?

Answer (score 1):

experience is in your state, so you have to use the setState method like :

```
this.setState({experience: response.data.experience})
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at SearchForm.js:37` in this case

Comment: it is a scoping issue. you need to declare var _ this = this; outside the callback and use _this in the callback

Comment: Yes, or you can use arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solution work for you ? Let me know!

Edit: Added conditional rendering for your `<option>` if your `experience` is not yet defined

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        position: "",
        area: "",
        date: "",
        experience: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => [],
        },
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps = NextProps => {
    if (NextProps.experience !== this.props.experience) {
        this.setState({ experience: NextProps.experience });
    }
};

componentDidMount() {

    axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://example.com/dictionaries/",
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)",
            "HH-User-Agent": "React App/1.0 (myemail@gmail.com)",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.experience);
            this.setState({ experience: response.data.experience });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form className="form search-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-row">
                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label htmlFor="experience">Experience</label>
                    <select
                        className="form-control"
                        name="experience"
                        id="experience"
                        onChange={this.handleExperienceChange}
                        value={this.state.experience}
                    >
                        {this.state.experience.length > 0 && 
                        <option
                            key={this.state.experience.id}
                            value={this.state.experience.name}
                        >
                            {this.state.experience.name}
                        </option> }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined at SearchForm.js:37` in `this.setState({ experience: response.data.experience });`

Comment: Updated my answer, what does it say now ? Could be a `this` scope issue

Comment: I used your code `.then((response) => {
            this.setState({experience: response.data.experience});
            console.log(this.experience);
            })` but `console.log(this.experience);` - undefined

Comment: You need to do: `.then((response) => { this.setState({experience: response.data.experience}, () => console.log(this.state.experience));`

Comment: ok, it helped. but `{this.state.experience.length > 0 && 
                        <option
                            key={this.state.experience.id}
                            value={this.state.experience.name}
                        >
                            {this.state.experience.name}
                        </option> }` doesn't work, options are empty

Comment: What if you replace it by: `{this.state.experience && ...` ?

Comment: Maybe I need to use loop here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167161/discussion-between-drunkdevkek-and-heidel).